# mysql - comprobar si una consulta select es mayor a 0

Tags: mysql

Buenas, estoy creando un procedimiento almacenado de registro de usuario.
Mi procedimiento almacenado:

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists sp_insertar_usuario;
create procedure sp_insertar_usuario
(
in idpersona int,
in usuario varchar(20),
in pass varchar(45),
in imagen varchar(400),
in email varchar(45)
)
begin
insert into seg_usuario(perso_id, usu_nom, usu_pass, usu_imagen, usu_freg, usu_est, usu_email) 
values(idpersona, usuario, pass, imagen,now(),"Activo",email);
end //
delimiter ;
```

Todo funciona normal, la idea es que antes de hacer el **insert** el procedimiento verifique si el idpersona que se va a utilizar, ya se ha usado con otro usuario.
Pensaba en algo como esto:

```
begin
set @resp = select count(*) from segu_usuario where perso_id = idpersona;
if @resp > 0 then
select 'REPETIDO'
else
insert into seg_usuario(perso_id, usu_nom, usu_pass, usu_imagen, usu_freg, usu_est, usu_email) 
values(idpersona, usuario, pass, imagen,now(),"Activo",email);
select 'OK'
end if;

end //
```

Pero el procedimiento no se crea. Alguna solucion, o alternativa? Se los agradezco de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lo que quieres es que revise que el idPersona, para eso existen los campos en la base de datos con constraint `unique`, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
go
    ALTER TABLE seg_usuario
ADD CONSTRAINT NombreConstraint UNIQUE (idPersona);
go
```

Con esto, la base de datos entiende con `unique` que el valor de ese campo **no puede duplicarse**, de tal manera que, si intentas agregar otro registro con un valor igual, saltará una exepción.
Para más información consulta [este enlace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/ms190024.aspx)

Comment: Es una buena opción, en caso de que busques unicidad por esa columna.

Comment: no lo especifica en la pregunta, pero supongo que es lo que desea.